# Google Analytics 4 - accessing custom dimensions

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have created a couple of custom dimensions for my property:

| Dimension name | Scope | Property/Parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| event_category | Event | event_category |
| event_label | Event | event_label |

When I monitor my website in the analytics debugger, these parameters are in the  events that I see for my GA4 tag:

```
form_submission - Google Analytics Hit
    Page Location   dl  https://16v8x.elite80-001.ihousedev.com/contact
    Page Referrer   dr  https://tagassistant.google.com/
    Event Name  en  form_submission
    System Property _ee 1
    Event Parameter ep.event_category   lead
    Event Parameter ep.event_label  Contact Us

    API Call: 
    gtag("event", "form_submission", {event_category: "lead", event_label: "Contact Us"})

    Data Layer:
    {
      event: "form_submission",
      gtm: {uniqueEventId: 9, start: 1684510761995, priorityId: undefined},
      eventModel: {
        event_category: "lead",
        event_label: "Contact Us",
        send_to: "MY TAG"
      }
    }
```

So I felt that adding the custom dimensions would make them available in my reports. But they don't seem to be.

```
$dimensions = [
        new Dimension( ['name' => 'eventName'] ),
        new Dimension( ['name' => 'customEvent:event_category' ]),
        new Dimension( ['name' => 'customEvent:event_label' ]),
    ];
$metrics = [
        new Metric( ['name' => 'totalUsers'] ),
    ];

$date_range = new DateRange( [ 'start_date' => '2023-04-28', 
                               'end_date'   => date('Y-m-d')
                             ] );

$report_params = 
    [
        'property'   => "properties/MY PROPERTY ID",
        'dateRanges' => [ $date_range ],
        'dimensions' => $dimensions,
        'metrics'    => $metrics,
    ];

$response = $client->runReport( $report_params );
```

If I omit the two new custom dimensions, I get most of the events I expect. But if I include either or both, I get nothing. Do I have the specification for the custom dimensions wrong? Or do I need to wait for events I triggered after creating the new dimensions? I assumed that the values for category and label would be there in existing events, but perhaps I'm wrong. The long delay between performing actions on my website and the events showing up in GA4 is dramatically slowing my testing down.

Comment: They will only show in future events, so you will have to wait. If you export to BigQuery it receives all dimensions and metrics even if they have no custom definitions set up.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. That confirms it for me. I don't think the BigQuery option would work for us, but I'll look into that too.